# Textview Letter spacing not working properly in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-support-library

I'm trying to set letter spacing to -0.03 to bring the letters more closer. I can get that done by using `android:letterSpacing="-0.03"` attribute. Which works fine in most cases. However when the text is larger than 50 characters it get's messed up and does not work properly.

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!"
        android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

This is what it looks like without letter spacing with `more than 50 characters`. Which works like it's suppose to.

[image]

This is what it looks like with letter spacing with `less then 50 characters` Which works like it's suppose to.

[image]

And This is what it looks like with letter spacing with `more then 50 characters`. You can see how there is no `ellipsize` at the end of the text.

[image]